# make button be vertical center in the div

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm working on the front page as below[image]:.

I tried to make create, update and delete buttons a litter bit higher so that their height is as same as the middle between Project: [7] Example Project and 7 items.

The following are the HTML code and CSS code where you can find that I create a mybtn class and try to use `vertical-align:center;` but it doesn't work. Any suggestions would be great!

```
<div>
  <div>
    <h2>Project: [{{items.length}}] Example Project </h2>
      <p>{{items.length}} items
          <button (click)='onDelete()' type="button" class="btn float-right btn-space mybtn">delete</button>
          <button (click)='onUpdate()' type="button" class="btn float-right btn-space mybtn">update</button>
          <button (click)='onCreate()' type="button" class="btn float-right btn-space mybtn">create</button>
      </p>
  </div>

<table class="table table-bordered table-striped margin">
    <thead>
          <tr>
              <th>select</th>
              <th>No.</th>
              <th>Company</th>
              <th>CCO No.</th>
              <th>Budget Code</th>
              <th>Description</th>
              <th>Award Date</th>
              <th>Sent Date</th>
              <th>Cost Status</th>
              <th>Committed Amount</th>
          </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr *ngFor="let item of items">
          <td><input type="checkbox" (change)="checkbox(item, $event)" [(ngModel)]="item.flag"></td> 
          <td>{{item.No}}</td>
          <td>{{item.Company}}</td>
          <td>{{item.CCO_No}}</td>
          <td>{{item.Budget_Code}}</td>
          <td>{{item.Description}}</td>
          <td>{{item.Award_Date}}</td>
          <td>{{item.Sent_Date}}</td>
          <td>{{item.Cost_Status}}</td>
          <td>{{item.Committed_Amount}}</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
  </table>
```

CSS file as follows:

```
.btn-space {
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 10 cm;
    margin-top: 10 cm;

  }

  .table td, .table th, .table input {
    text-align: center;   
 }

 .mybtn {
  vertical-align:center; 
 }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should enclose the h2 in a div and float it left, and similarly enclose the buttons in div and float them right and set some padding to this div, finally the items counter paragraph can be enclosed in another div and do clear both on it.

You can change your header div from this

```
<div>
    <h2>Project: [{{items.length}}] Example Project </h2>
    <p>{{items.length}} items
        <button (click)='onDelete()' type="button" class="btn float-right btn-space mybtn">delete</button>
        <button (click)='onUpdate()' type="button" class="btn float-right btn-space mybtn">update</button>
        <button (click)='onCreate()' type="button" class="btn float-right btn-space mybtn">create</button>
    </p>
</div>
```

to this:

```
<div>
    <div style="float:left;">
        <h2>Project: [{{items.length}}] Example Project </h2>
    </div>
    <div style="float:right; padding:20px;">
        <button (click)='onDelete()' type="button" class="btn float-right btn-space mybtn">delete</button>
        <button (click)='onUpdate()' type="button" class="btn float-right btn-space mybtn">update</button>
        <button (click)='onCreate()' type="button" class="btn float-right btn-space mybtn">create</button>
    </div>
    <div style="clear:both;">
        <p>{{items.length}} items</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

to get the desired result. I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

As quick fix you can just do:

```
.mybtn {
  position: relative;
  top: -10px;
}
```

`vertical-align` is not for this.

Answer (score 1):

Since you posted this under the `bootstrap-4` tag, I'm assuming that you are looking for a clean Bootstrap 4 solution (instead of relying on css hacks).

If that is the case, the solution is rather simple (and doesn't require any custom css whatsoever):

First, you create a new row inside the main column and then you put 2 columns inside. Your headline and paragraph go into the first inner column and the buttons in the second.

All you need to do then is just add the classes `d-flex align-items-center justify-content-end` to the buttons column. Done!

To provide some spacing to the buttons, I replaced your custom css with the native Bootstrap 4 class `mr-1` (margin-right 1 unit).

Finally, to center the text inside the table, I added the `text-center` class to that. The `table-responsive` class makes sure that the table isn't gonna break the layout on smaller screens.

Here's the complete, working code snippet (click the "run code snippet" button below):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                    <h2>Project: [7] Example Project </h2>
                    <p>7 items</p>
                </div>
                <div class="col d-flex align-items-center justify-content-end">
                    <button (click)='onDelete()' type="button" class="btn mr-1">delete</button>
                    <button (click)='onUpdate()' type="button" class="btn mr-1">update</button>
                    <button (click)='onCreate()' type="button" class="btn">create</button>
                </div>
            </div>

            <table class="table text-center table-responsive table-bordered table-striped margin">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>select</th>
                        <th>No.</th>
                        <th>Company</th>
                        <th>CCO No.</th>
                        <th>Budget Code</th>
                        <th>Description</th>
                        <th>Award Date</th>
                        <th>Sent Date</th>
                        <th>Cost Status</th>
                        <th>Committed Amount</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr *ngFor="let item of items">
                        <td><input type="checkbox" (change)="checkbox(item, $event)" [(ngModel)]="item.flag"></td>
                        <td>No</td>
                        <td>Company</td>
                        <td>CCO</td>
                        <td>Budget</td>
                        <td>Description</td>
                        <td>Award_Date</td>
                        <td>Sent_Date</td>
                        <td>500</td>
                        <td>1000</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the css code, for 'mybtn class', use **middle** instead of **center**:

```
.mybtn {
  vertical-align:middle; 
}
```